# Using z-Score for multiple comparisons

Tags: multiple-comparisons, z-score

I have data collected from three groups and I would like to calculate the z-score using the grand mean and variance of the combined three groups. Would it be possible to then compare the z-scores of each subgroup and thereby check if they all 3 groups are taken from one population? Would this method allow me to circumvent multiple comparisons correction?

Comment: Nothing circumvents the multiple comparisons problem except not doing multiple comparisons. How **much** of a problem it is is a matter of some disagreement and has been discussed here.

If you want to compare 3 groups on some continuous variable, the first thing to think of is a linear model (ANOVA/regression) do you have a reason for rejecting those?

Comment: @PeterFlom, the data is derived from a neurophysiological experiment and needs to be normalize/z-scored prior to any further analysis. I was wondering what is the easiest way to compare the three groups given the z-scores.

Comment: You can use a linear model on the standardized data. Some people recommend this as a routine matter.